# Extend identity for SMS OTP based login

Tags: authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have trying to implment one time registration verification & daily login using SMS OTP for my app using asp.net core identity implementation.

> It is one time token, which should expire in 15 minutes if not used
>
> User should request it again in case its expired or lost

Searching around for it, all the implementation provide details about MFA or Google Authenticator based verification, where this scenario is slightly different.

> The Token will not be generated by the Server, and not the Authenticator app.
>
> I need to store token along with its genrated at time.
>
> The token will be 6 digit SMS.

The scenario is more similar to `password less auth` [mentioned here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Implementing-Mediums-Passwordless-Authentication-using-ASPNET-Core-Identity), but then the token in that case is not stored, I need to store it with Validity, not sure how to extend .net core identity to match above requirement.

This is fairly standard way of phone number authentication

I know this is not a standard SO format, but I am at loss from where to start

Comment: [Two-factor authentication with SMS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1).. What it appears you're talking about is Two Factor Authentication (2FA).

Comment: It sounds like you want a "One Time Password" authentication, using .Net Core (presumably 2.x or 3.x).  You didn't specify a particular implementation. A simple Google search turned up several hits, including [Two-factor authentication with SMS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1), https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-set-up-two-factor-authentication-on-asp-net-core-using-google-authenticator-4b15d0698ec9/ and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-up-two-factor-authentication-in-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: @ErikPhilips what I am looking at is login using SMS OTP, rather than password

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I found myself here with the same problem, and information about this is surprisingly thin on the ground. Likely as Microsoft recommend using (2FA) authenticator apps, using a Time-based One-time Password Algorithm (TOTP) rather than an OTP with SMS/Email.

Not the intended purpose, but nevertheless the following will allow you to generate and save a time limited (3 minutes) 6 digit OTP, associate it with a user and then use it to verify them using ASP.NET Core Identity.

**GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync**

```
var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, model.PhoneNumber);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatechangephonenumbertokenasync

and

**VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync**

```
 bool valid = await _userManager.VerifyChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync(user, code, model.PhoneNumber);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.verifychangephonenumbertokenasync

---

This can be seen being implemented in the documentation posted by Erik & paulsm4

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/2fa?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.1

A link to the code
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/2fa/sample/Web2FA

A link to the controller where this is implemented
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/2fa/sample/Web2FA/Controllers/ManageController.cs

Comment: thanks a lot for this.. really happy to have a solution... I never though I could use `GenerateChangePhoneNumberTokenAsync` to generate login tokens, but this would still do, as a workaround.